# Argument of type 'typeof <classname>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => <classname>'

Tags: typescript

I get the following error

```
Argument of type 'typeof Settings' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => Settings'
```

in the following line

```
new JsonConvert().deserialize(Settings.Get(), Settings)
```

The docs of [json2typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2typescript) are saying that i should pass a `classReference` as the second parameter. Their example is like mine.

Here is a simplification of the `Settings` class

```
export default class Settings {
  constructor(a: number) {
    this._a= a;
  }

  @JsonProperty('_a', Number)
  private _a: number;

  get A() {
    return this._a;
  }

  set A(newA: number) {
    this._a= newA;
  }

  static Get(): string {
    return <someJson>;
  }


  static GetObj(): Settings {
    return new JsonConvert().deserializeObject(Settings.Get(), Settings);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post more of the code? How does the `Settings` class look ? If i had to guess I would say it is either abstract, has a private constructor or something else is not ok with the constructor

Comment: Have added the settings class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deserializeObject` requires a class with a constructor that takes no arguments.

```
export default class Settings {
  constructor(a?: number) {
    this._a = a!;
  }

  @JsonProperty('_a', Number)
  private _a: number;

  get A() {
    return this._a;
  }

  set A(newA: number) {
    this._a= newA;
  }

  static Get(): string {
    return "{}";
  }


  static GetObj(): Settings {
    return new JsonConvert().deserializeObject(Settings.Get(), Settings);
  }
}
```

Comment: @huckjulius, it's just a semantic error, at run-time, `JsonConvert` would invoke the constructor without a parameter. This probably was ok as it would later set `a` but it was a mismatch between the contract  `JsonConvert`  expected and the implementation you provided